# Manipulate Listplot of table

Tags: plotting, manipulate, warning-messages

There is a simple code  but it doesn't work

```
Manipulate[
ListPlot[
{Table[
{Sin[Pi/4 Cos[t]], -Cos[Pi/4  Cos[t]]}, {t, 1, n, 0.1}]}], {n, 1, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: no problem with V 10.3

Comment: works just fine on my Mac, MMA 10.0

Comment: I have a *Mathematica* 10.4

Comment: And I have the same problem as you, vito; Mathematica 10.4 on Windows 10

Comment: me too, I have a Windows 10

Comment: it works fine on Wolfram Development Platform (10.4.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (February 26, 2016) ). If you want you can try yourself, it's free.

Comment: MMA 10.2, Windows 7.  Same thing.  Eventually with enough tries (with resetting the "Dynamic Updating Enabled") it eventually works.

Comment: Works fine on MMA 10.4.0.0 on Win7-64

Comment: Also works fine for "10.4.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (February 26, 2016)" on Windows 10.